# Python testing with parameterization from function return

Tags: pytest

I've been trying to solve a python test using `pytest` but have not been able to find an example configuration that works - though some are close. Here is my case study:

```
@pytest.fixture
def vil_check():
   code
   return [(v1,v2,v3), (...), (...)]

@pytest.mark.parameterize("v1,v2,v3", vil_check):
def test_one(v1,v2,v3):
      assert v1 < 2
      assert v2 > 5
      ....
```

I'm trying to follow this example:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 6), ("6*9", 42)])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected
```

But using a `fixture` to supply the list: `[("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 6), ("6*9", 42)]`.

However, this configuration doesn't work:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("v1, v2, v3", vil_check)
def test_max(v1, v2, v3):
   assert abs(v1) <= 5
```

The error is that pytest doesn't see vil_check return as iterable.
There seems to be a way to use `pytest_generate_tests` to accomplish this but I'm drawing a blank on how to write it.

Comment: You cannot use a fixture in `pytest.mark.parametrize`, nor can you use it in `pytest_generate_tests `. Is there a reason why you need a fixture and cannot just use a function here?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen  I need the information that is dynamically created in the function `vil_check`. This information can will varying which is why I need to parameterize the test so that the number of tests run equals the number of values returned by `vil_check`. How can I do this using pytest?

Comment: i still dont get why you need `vil_check` to be a **fixture**. Is it like it's being used elsewhere as well?

Comment: @Shod I don't need it to be a fixture. Can I call it from within the test? How then can I populate the list for `pytest.mark.parametrize`. I'm asking how to do this given the nature of the case study.

Comment: Just make the fixture a normal function (e.g. remove the decorator) and use it like you do now.

Comment: I think what I missed in my code the first time I tried this was to call `vil_check` as `vil_check()`. Leaving out the parentheses caused an error that was not clear and I went down a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's comment, because `vil_check` need not be a fixture, here's what you can do - remove the `fixture` decorator from `vil_check` and `call` it in `mark.parametrize` below:

```py
def vil_check():
   # code
   yield from [(v1,v2,v3), (...), (...)]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("v1,v2,v3", vil_check()):
def test_one(v1,v2,v3):
      assert v1 < 2
      assert v2 > 5
      # code
```

Few points:

- you have spelled `parametrized` wrong, this may give you error if you have set `--strict-markers`.
- the decorator should not have a `:`
- for performance, i used `yield from` instead of `return` in `vil_check`. This will be efficient in case the list is huge

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes per your suggestions and incorporated the points. The test works as I hoped.